# IsSet (trick) instead strlen, form manipulation by user

Tags: php, arrays, isset

For example we create a form

```
<input class="k_nip_3" name="k_nip" placeholder=""  type="text" value="" />
```

and we create a rule(min 5. chars):

```
if (IsSet($_POST['k_nip'][4])) // now corect*
```

But our user is clever and manipulates our form.

Create and send :

```
<input class="k_nip_3" name="k_nip[5]" placeholder=""  type="text" value="aa" />
```

And

```
IsSet($_POST['k_nip'][5])
```

accept this.

How can I best avoid this situation?

Comment: something wrong with strlen()?

Comment: its not a clear trick, due to its limitations its a poor alternative. and if its speed difference effects your site, you have much bigger issues to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

So what is wrong with

```
if (isset($_POST['k_nip']) && strlen($_POST['k_nip']) >= 5)
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure why the original poster doesn't want to use strlen?

Comment: IsSet is faster than strlen :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955913/isset-vs-strlen-a-fast-clear-string-length-calculation
And I tried with this trick, and found problem with arrays

Comment: I think he's looking for a test on the 5th element: `isset($_POST['k_nip'][5]) && strlen($_POST['k_nip'][5]) >= 5)` but I'd have to agree with your answer otherwise, no better way to do it.

Comment: Have you benchmarked the difference?  http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html

Comment: @JanCzarny: You really shouldn't be worrying about speed unless you're comparing a million strings, or really long strings.  With strings 5 characters long, the difference is probably not noticeable.

Comment: @phatskat: `$_POST['k_nip']` is a string, not an array.  The problem is if the user edits the HTML, thus making it an array.

Comment: He's looking to make sure there is a character in the 6th position.  Which actually would make is rule need to be `iiset($_POST['k_nip'][4])`, not since the string is 0 indexed.

Comment: How funny that @codinghorror got me into StackExchange (as more than a place Google would take me) and here it is again : P Also, yes, isset is considerably faster than strlen but there is no reason to ignore strlen as the gains are minimal and, in all likelyhood, invisible when processing a form. And what problem with arrays?

Comment: @Rocket, Ok but what, if we create page for millions visits per day?

Comment: @JanCzarny Use strlen(). Or use Javascript to validate the input (at least as a starting point). Slicing the string at [5] to test length isn't a great idea to begin with, plain and simple. You highlighted why it's a poor practice above in that you _could_ get an array instead of a string and then your `isset` isn't helpful. More robust validation is necessary, but again, I really doubt you're going to have that many people editing the HTML. Doing serious checks for things like XSS are much more important.

Comment: @JanCzarny Thanks, hope I didn't come across too overbearing - if you have the right tools, use them :]

Answer (score 1):

With a clever user, you just have to validate it the oldfashioned way, thoroughly; and not go microoptimising.