# Double loop removing items on the fly

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I want to remove words from a dictionary given certain conditions.
I would like to do so that in the next iteration the dictionary will calculate over the new one, that has that last item removed, so it won't calculate again.

```
// sample data
    $dict = ['aaa', 'aaan','aba', 'abat', 'ime', 'iso', 'nime', 'tiso',];
    $unique = ['abatiso', 'aaanime'];

  // could use while to further optimize unset (and remove on the fly) http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#88578
    while (list($key_word, $word) = each($unique)) { // $key is unused, just for the optimization that the whille provides
      foreach ($dict as $key_other => $other) {

// ... conditions calculations

        unset($unique[$key_word]);
 }
}
    echo "n compounds: " . count($compounds) . NL;
```

If I set the inner loop with a while instead foreach as the outer, I get 0 results, it terminates inmediately.

For now, I'm getting duplicate results like:

> ```
>                // Removed: abatiso => wc: aba + tiso = abatiso
>                 // Removed: abatiso => wc: abat + iso = abatiso
>                 // Removed: abatiso => wc: abati + so = abatiso
>                 // Removed: abatiso => wc: abatis + o = abatiso
> ```

How can I make it so it removes the word and won't proccess it again on next iteration?

Some test data:

```
Removed: aaaaaah => wc: aaaa + aah = aaaaaah
Removed: aaaaaah => wc: aaaaaa + h = aaaaaah
Removed: aaaaargh => wc: aaa + aargh = aaaaargh
Removed: aaaalead => wc: aaaa + lead = aaaalead
Removed: aaabbbccc => wc: aaab + bbccc = aaabbbccc
Removed: aaacomix => wc: aaa + comix = aaacomix
Removed: aaagak => wc: aaa + gak = aaagak
Removed: aaahh => wc: aaa + hh = aaahh
Removed: aaainc => wc: aaa + inc = aaainc
Removed: aaainc => wc: aaai + nc = aaainc
Removed: aaanet => wc: aaa + net = aaanet
Removed: aaanet => wc: aaan + et = aaanet
Removed: aaanime => wc: aaa + nime = aaanime
Removed: aaanime => wc: aaan + ime = aaanime
Removed: aaaron => wc: aaa + ron = aaaron
Removed: aabbcc => wc: aab + bcc = aabbcc
Removed: aabmup => wc: aab + mup = aabmup
Removed: aabre => wc: aab + re = aabre
Removed: aabybro => wc: aaby + bro = aabybro
Removed: aacap => wc: aac + ap = aacap
Removed: aacap => wc: aaca + p = aacap
Removed: aaccording => wc: aac + cording = aaccording
Removed: aacd => wc: aac + d = aacd
Removed: aachener => wc: aach + ener = aachener
Removed: aachener => wc: aachen + er = aachener
Removed: aacisuan => wc: aaci + suan = aacisuan
Removed: aacisuan => wc: aacis + uan = aacisuan
Removed: aacult => wc: aac + ult = aacult
```

I'm not using a break inside the inner loop because I have to do calculations also.

Comment: Please be more specific on your question and code.

Comment: @Eiko What you don't understand?

Comment: I'm currently thinking something like a ``for ($i=0; $i<count($dict);$i++) ...`` instead the foreach and $i-- if I remove one item :?

Comment: You're not showing much of your code at all. You do show some random output, which we cannot relate to anything - we just cannot make any sense of it. Please construct a minimal example with input, output, and your code.

Comment: The comparations inside doesn't matter here. The question is how to iterate and remove on the fly. If you read in detail you can get it. I add chewed array examples

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your code. You set the `$key` value in two places with two different meanings. At first you assign it in the `list(..` statement and then again in the `foreach` loop as key value holder for the values in `$dict`.

As a rule of thumb it is never good to unset elements from a list while you are iterating over that list. You better save the items you processed in a list and don't process them again. If you want to you can remove those items later on, **after** you finished the loop over `unique`.

If I understand your question correctly this would be a way to go:

```
$toUnset = [];
foreach ($unique as $key => $word) {
    if (!in_array($word, $toUnset)) {
        foreach ($dict as $other) {

            //do your processing
            $toUnset[] = $word;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not using $key, the code is a bit messy of so many ongoing changes and tries, I will correct.
I'd prefer to do that on the fly so it runs faster, because currently takes almost 24h to run :D

Comment: How many items does your dict have ? 24 hours sounds like a serious runtime problem.

Comment: Only 300k and 110k. I think that some strlen and strpos and a custom  binary_search (instead of builtin php in_array/search, because dicts are sorted) inside the loop are getting it too slow. 
I'm trying the isset vs strlen hack (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6955913/isset-vs-strlen-a-fast-clear-string-length-calculation), looks, promissing