# PHP, 'Haystack contains Needle?'

Tags: php

Assuming this works properly for telling if a substring is in a string, is there a more concise way to do this?

```
if(is_int(strpos($haystack, $needle))){
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't do it that way. Just make a strict comparison to `FALSE`.

```
$found = strpos($haystack, $needle) !== FALSE;
```

Comment: @bfavaretto It's a needless extra function call, which among other things is [expensive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691625/why-are-php-function-calls-so-expensive).

Comment: This is correct, strpos returns FALSE when no needle is found.

Answer (score 3):

Not really. It really comes down to your preference for which one is the clearest way to express what you're doing.  Some alternatives:

```
if( strpos( $h, $n ) !== FALSE ){
    // stuff
}

if( strpos( $h, $n ) > -1 ){
    // stuff
}
```

The most common approach is probably to use the strict `FALSE` comparison, so if you're working on an open-source project or have a lot of other people using your code, consider that option.