# Print false in php

Tags: php, syntax, boolean

I am trying to print the following statement:

```
print false . "\n" . true . "\n";
echo false . (bool)false . "\n" . true . "\n";
print "0" . "\n" . true . "\n";
```

The result that I am getting is just "1 1 0 1".
The expected result is:

> 0
>     1
>     0
>     1
>     0
>     1

I am using PHP 5.4.3 MSVC9 x64
Can someone please explain why and how I can make it print the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. Use an array.

```
$boolarray = Array(false => 'false', true => 'true');
echo $boolarray[false],"  ", $boolarray[true];
```

Output : `false true`

Comment: @Lion Do you know how to print them on two lines?

Comment: `echo $boolarray[false],"<br/>", $boolarray[true];`? Simply using a line-feed `<br/>`.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted but it will have to do. I would prefer a solution from within the language so I won't need to decalre / import this array every time.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4948663/php-get-bool-to-echo-false-when-false) question. What I mentioned in my answeris also there. I have just found it. Also, tried `echo (int)$bool_val;` as mentioned there in of the answers but unfortunately it also didn't work.

Comment: @Lion I tried that. I also tried Intval. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Tried much more. Apart from all of them, `echo (string)$var` should have done the job but it also didn't work as your requirement.

Comment: In brief, you need to check conditionally like `if(true) echo "true"; else echo "false";` or the same thing using the ternary/conditional operator. If you are able to find a concise solution, don't forget to share here.

Comment: @Lion `<br />` is not a line feed, but a line break.

Comment: @Cole Johnson:) Good call. I was just sleepy and forgot that "*`<br/>` stands for **break***".

Answer (score 10):

Your problem comes from your misconception of the `+` operator on strings in PHP. The string concatenation operator is `.` as PHP is loosely typed, it doesn't know if you want to concat or add the strings.

I'll break it down for you:

```
print false + "\n" + true + "\n";
echo false+(bool)false + "\n" + true + "\n";
print "0" + "\n" + true + "\n";
```

First off you might want to pick to stay with `echo` or `print`. Now, onward:

```
print false + "\n" + true + "\n";
```

PHP strings, [when added (not contacted)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php), evaluate to `0`. So this statement evaluates to:

```
print 0 + 0 + 1 + 0;
```

which is `1`. The other ones follow suit. If you want your code to work, you should use the concatenation operator (`.`). If you want to write `True` or `False` like how .NET does, you could write a simple function:

```
function writeBool($var)
{
    echo ($var) ? "True" : "False";
}
```

As per PHP's loose typing (which sucks if you ask me), anything that will [evaluate to `true`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php), will write "True". I would still discourage from using a function to do this as [function calls in PHP are *expensive*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691625).

Comment: explanation to follow shortly... but already has +5 :P Now **THAT** is hype!

Comment: A very good explanation just doesn't solve my problem

Comment: @RandallFlagg added a little function. PHP is loosely typed and `false` is just defined as 0: `define("false", 0);`. Same for true: `define("true", 1);`

Comment: @ColeJohnson That's... really not how it is.

Comment: @Juhana its just explination. It's not how they really are. :/ (unless you're C or C++)

Comment: "The moon is made of cheese. It's not really, it's just an explanation."

Comment: @ColeJohnson Why "echo true" gives 1 but "echo false" doesn't print?

Comment: @RandallFlagg http://ideone.com/AiROT I have no idea.

Comment: @ColeJohnson Do you know why it doesn't break lines?

Comment: @RandallFlagg Probably because you're looking at it in a web browser. Either choose "View source" in the browser or change the newlines to `<br>`s.

Comment: I was right here in this thread before I clicked on Cole Johnson's profile to find out that he is 15. Kudos to Cole Johnson. I started thinking about typesystems when I turned 21.