# Are isset() and !== null equivalent?

Tags: php, null

Since `isset` appears to be a function (http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php), there might be some overhead for calling it. So I wonder if using `!== null` instead of `isset` would produce faster code while, most importantly, keeping the code's behavior exactly the same?

Comment: `isset` is a language construct, not a function.

Comment: They are not the same. If your variable is not set, `isset` will not produce a warning - you are effectively saying, by using this function, that this is okay. If you use `!==` then you'll get a warning if the variable is not set.

Comment: deceze wrote [this article](http://kunststube.net/isset/) on `isset`, `empty`, `!$var` and all that... read it to fully understand the differences and pitfals

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From PHP Manual:

isset — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

isset Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

The function call overhead is so small you probably don't need to worry about it.
Read this post: [Why are PHP function calls *so* expensive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691625/why-are-php-function-calls-so-expensive)

> Note that isset is not a function (it has a special opcode for it), so it's faster.

Answer (score 1):

What about $foo = NULL, a variable can be set, and also be null

Answer (score 0):

`isset` is not a function, It is a `Language construct` in PHP, It is much faster.

`isset` determines if a variable is set and is not NULL.

Answer (score 0):

as above isset is to check if a variable is set and is not NULL. To make sure I usually use it as

```
if( isset( $var ) === TRUE )
{
 // Do what you want
}
```

This doesn't throw any unnecessary notices in PHP

Comment: There is no need for check TRUE. isset Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise.